# En VS 2019 excluir de la publicación web la carpeta wwwroot de un proyecto referenciado

Tags: asp.net-core

Tengo un proyecto web (AspNET Core - Razor Pages) que hace referencia a otro pero al momento de publicar el proyecto principal también se publica todo el proyecto referenciado y lo que quiero conseguir es que no se publique la carpeta wwwroot del proyecto referenciado. Sé como hacer para que no se publiquen carpetas o archivos del proyecto principal, pero no las del proyecto referenciado.

Muchas gracias por la ayuda que puedan brindar.

Answer (score 0):

Actualmente pareces que tienes algo asi

- Proyecto Web 1
- Proyecto Web 2

Y estas referenciandose, lo ideal sería para compartir "elementos" que necestias (generalmente controllers, vistas, Viewcomponents, etc) generes en un  librería que tenga dichos componentes, así lo utilizas en los dos proyecto web finales (o donde requieras)
Entonces tendrias asi tus proyectos

- LibreriaComun
- Proyecto Web 1 (referencia a LibreriaComun)
- Proyecto Web 2 (referencia a LibreriaComun)

Lo bueno que desde .NET Core y NET6 tenemos componentes que nos ayudan a compartir y cargar mucho mas facil te dejo el enlace [Compartir controladores, vistas, Razor páginas y mucho más con elementos de aplicación](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/app-parts?view=aspnetcore-6.0). Dale una mirada como se realiza esta tarea

Genere un ejemplo sencillo para ver como organizarlo y tenerlo como referencia (si bien esta en .NET6, esto se puede realizar desde NET COre las primeras versiones que seguramente estas con NET3.1). Aqui el repositorio del ejemplo

- [ASP.NET Core Experiments > ApplicationPart](https://github.com/fernandezja/aspnetcore-experiments/tree/master/src/ApplicationPart)

Donde tienes basicamente:

- SharedComponents
- WebApplication1 (referencia a SharedComponents)

En la parte de *SharedComponents*, se comparte el controllador, y para que la vista se pueda utilizar esta "embebida" (mira la propiedades de la vista esta como EmbeddedResource )
En la parte de *WebApplication1* utilizamos ApplicationPart para descubrir, referenciar y utilizar estos elementos.

Esta parte es la de Program en *WebApplication1*

```
var assembly = typeof(SharedComponents.Controllers.JediController).Assembly;
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews()
            .AddApplicationPart(assembly)
            .AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();

builder.Services.Configure<MvcRazorRuntimeCompilationOptions>(
options => { 
    options.FileProviders.Add(new EmbeddedFileProvider(assembly)); 
});
```

Enlaces que te pueden servir:

- [Compartir controladores, vistas, Razor páginas y mucho más con elementos de aplicación](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/app-parts?view=aspnetcore-6.0)
- [Creación de una interfaz de usuario reutilizable con el proyecto de biblioteca de clases de Razor en ASP.NET Core](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/aspnet/core/razor-pages/ui-class?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio)

Espero que te sirva de ayuda o guía.